# Eslint, prevent to import from the same package

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

Is it possible to say to eslint to avoid to import from the same package?

I'm in a monorepo and I would like to block the dev and for sure the auto-import of some IDEs to import from the same package.

e.g.

```js
// inside the @lib/utils
import { convertNames } from @lib/utils
```

I'd like to force the Devs to use this approach instead

```js
// inside the @lib/utils
import {convertNames} from '../../someWhere'
```

I tried with `eslint-plugin-import` and `no-restricted-imports` without success.

any suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: Hey Marco! Would love to help you, but I need some extra info. I didn't understand your explanation. Are you trying to make eslint always throw an error if imported from `@lib/utils`? or only when you are inside a specific folder you want to throw an error on the aliased import (to prevent circular dependencies)?

Comment: exact that way I'd like to avoid circular dependencies within the aliases too

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

1. Create an ESLint configuration for the entire project, preferring the path aliases
2. Create an override configuration for each path alias folder to prefer avoid the path aliases and encourage relative paths

if you use a javascript file for your `.eslintrc`, you can even do it programatically.

### Manual Configuration (will need to add new paths by hand)

```js
// https://json.schemastore.org/eslintrc
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  globals: {
    MyGlobal: true,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.ts", "*.js"],
      parserOptions: {
        project: ["tsconfig.json"],
        createDefaultProgram: true,
      },
      rules: {
        "no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            patterns: [
              {
                group: ["*someWhere"],
                message: "Please use our path alias `@lib/utils` instead.",
              }
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      files: [
        "**/someWhere/**/*.js",
        "**/someWhere/**/*.ts"
      ],
      rules: {
        "no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            patterns: [
              {
                group: ["@lib/utils"],
                message: "Please avoid using @lib/utils in this folder to avoid circular dependencies. Use relative paths instead.",
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

If you want to generate the overrides programmatically, you can read your `tsconfig` and get the paths and their folders there. then, generate this override for all those paths so it will make all the path aliases you define avoid those circular dependencies.